# Android guiding application

Tags: java, android, mapping

I am creating an Android application in which the user searches for the position of a book in a library.
My issue is with the way I am going to draw the bookshelves and the shortest route that the user is going to follow from his position.
One idea is to implement an a matrix but I don't think it really works so I would like some help if possible.
This is the implementation of the library in paint (the green lines are the routes in a way the user can take to get to the book):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can create a model of library hall as a graph and search for shortest path from one vertex (current user location) to another (location of book) using [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). Each vertex of graph is a real point in the library hall. Weight of each graph edge is real distance between these points. Algorithm is quite simple to implement and well described in Wikipedia.